# margin-top: auto не работает

Tags: html, css, margin, auto

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как работает margin-top: auto? не могу прибить текст к низу, хотя у родителя высоту большую указал, или надо что то еще делать?

Comment: Возможно вам для колонки необходимо задать тоже `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно дать родителю блока два свойства:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно растянуть карточки на всю высоту.

Для этого родителю карточек назначаем следующие правила.

```
.cards {
  display: flex; /* Используем флексбокс */
  align-items: streach; /* streach будет растягивать */
}
```

А самим карточкам выставить

```
.card {
  display: flex;  /* Опять же флексбокс */
  flex-direction: column; /* Порядок содержимого - column (друг под другом) */
  height: auto;  /* auto - растянет на всю высоту родителя */
}
```

А теперь уже нужному элементу можно задать `margin-top: auto;`, чтобы он прижался к низу карточки.

Демо:

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: streach;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.card__circle-progress,
.card__gradient-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.card__circle-progress {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card__gradient-text {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}

.card__text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__circle-progress">9 лет</div>
    <div class="card__text">Репутация проверенная временем!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__gradient-text">3 715</div>
    <div class="card__text">Более чем 3000 довольных клиентов по всей России</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__circle-progress">7 000 +</div>
    <div class="card__text">Тренажеров установлено в коммерческих и частных тренажерных залах</div>
  </div>
</div>
```